# ProgressBar running faster after each onclick in android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, android-progressbar, thread-sleep

I am Stuck here with this application in android. In my application i am trying to implement a progressbar which shows timer for certain seconds. When the Button is clicked the timer should refresh and again start from 0 in progressBar. For this I am using Thread.

The Problem is, When I Click the button the Thread calls the timer function and each time the thread is getting faster and faster. I couldn't resolve it and not having any idea what is going in background.
This is my code for Timerfunction

```
public void setTimer()
    {
        prog=0;
        progress.setProgress(prog);
        if(flag){
        t= new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
              while(prog<100)
              {
                prog+=1;
                handle.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run()
                    {
                        progress.setProgress(prog);
                        if(prog==progress.getMax()&& flag){
                         call_fun();
                        }
                    }
                });
                try
                {
                  Thread.sleep(time);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Log.i("Error", null);
                }
              }
            }
        });
        t.start(); 
        }
    }
```

I called this function in another function called RandomGeneration. If the button is clicked the randomgeneration is called and the set timer is activated everytime. But the progressbar is running faster after every click. It is constantly running in the same specific time. For example if it runs for 3 seconds in the first click, its running 2 seconds in the second click and getting faster considerably.

Can anyone please try to find what is happening in this code.
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see a new Thread is being created everytime you click the button.
Maybe try to check if `t` is already running and if so update it's logic to set progress to `0`?
Also, what does `if(flag)` do?

Comment: Thanks for ur response!! You can see from my code that i am setting the prog=0 everytime the function is called. And flag is a boolean, this application is similar to quiz if the answer is correct it the flag is true. If the answer is wrong then the flag is false. This quiz as a timer which should run for certain time. And it should refresh for every correct answer and new question is displayed.

Comment: Then I would suggest to do something like this
`if ( t != null ) {
  return;}`
And you really should set `prog` as volatile (if you're not doing it already)

Comment: If the thread is null then it finished its work right!! Where should i call if(t!=null )..  Are you telling me to call this in onclick?? Before that Can you please explain me why the thread is running faster each time??

Comment: You should check if it's null right before `t= new Thread(new Runnable()...`
I cannot say for sure without looking at the full code why it is running faster, but maybe some threads don't get GC and keep updating your progressbar.

Comment: Does this fix the progress bar speeding up?

Comment: Ya the thread is running.  if(t!=null)
    {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Thread is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return;
  }  What impact does it give when the thread is kept running in background ??

Comment: Ya it fixes :).. Thanks a lot... Could you please what was the problem ??

Comment: When you create a new Thread each time, the previous one will keep running its code. But I'm not entirely sure..
Glad to help :)

Comment: I couldn't get it.. I can understand that the previous thread is running and the newer thread should wait and start running after the thread. If that happens then it should delay and not speed up the process. Anyway its working now.. Thank you :)